# How to change default shell in FreeBSD?

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd, zsh, sh

The default shell in FreeBSD is `sh` and I really can't stand it: autocomplete is very limited, and rehash commands kill me. I feel like a one armed and one legged man...

How can I change the shell globally to `zsh` or `bash` - for root and for all current and future users?

Comment: Just tried this to update an existing user in FreeBSD 9.1 and the system prompted me to use the following: chpass -s /usr/local/bin/bash USER

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For existing users, use the [`chsh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chsh) command (“**ch**ange **sh**ell”):

```
chsh -s SHELL USER
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash root
```

For future users:

- Edit "`/etc/pw.conf`" `defaultshell` keywords
- When use `adduser()`, choose necessary shell

Comment: ...but be careful about changing the root shell to something from the ports tree (e.g., /usr/local/bin/bash), because if you screw something up during a port upgrade you may find yourself without root access.

Comment: s/feature/future/?

Comment: larsk: zsh can be build statically right..? [at least I saw parameter in "make config"]  so as far as I understand, it's a binary with all dependencies build in? so can I put /usr/local/bin/zsh to /bin/zsh ? root user can use old version it's ok.. then it would be safe?

Comment: Building it statically and copying it into /bin is probably the safest thing you can do.  I just leave root's shell set to `/bin/sh` and then `exec bash` on those rare occasions when I really need to log in as root (more often I just use `sudo` from my user account).

Comment: Note this must be run as root (or with `sudo`).